# Twig / Symfony2 Dynamic Template

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to do this kind of thing so that if a template doesn't exist it just renders the content. The below code won't work though as you can't code it like this.

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('twig_parent_template') != "" %}
    {% extends app.request.attributes.get('twig_parent_template') %}
    {% block title "The Title Here" %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}
Content here
{% endblock %}
```

Can I do this kind of thing somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twig extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html#dynamic-inheritance) has a good documentation on this topic.

Since you need to specify a template to extend, my thoughts go on creating a default template.

<kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/views/yourview.html.twig**</kbd>

```
{% set extender = app.request.attributes.get('twig_parent_template') ? : 'Bundle::default.html.twig' %}
{% extends extender %}

{% block title "Your title" %}
{% block content %}
    Your content
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/views/default.html.twig**</kbd>

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/views/parent.html.twig**</kbd>

```
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Doing such, if `app.request.attributes.get('twig_parent_template')` is set, it will render the template given in its value.
Otherwise, it will render `default.html.twig` containing only the `content` block